# Using a sqlite database instead of cookies to store login tokens

Tags: cookies, oauth, oauth-2.0, electron

After a user authenticates with a 3rd party service using OAuth2 and I get a login token, am I opening myself to security issues by saving this token in a sqlite database **on the users local machine** instead of using the Electron browserWindow cookies?

Since both cookies and the sqlite database exist in plaintext on the users machine, I don't think there's a difference. But I'm not sure if the browserWindow (and by extension, proper browsers like Chrome) take extra precautions in protecting cookies when the browser is **not** running.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this is *exactly* what Chromium/Chrome actually does when saving cookies: It stores them in a SQLite database, on a per-profile basis. On my system (Linux), I have found the "plain" cookies database to be located in `~/.config/chromium/Default/Cookies` and it is thus likely that Electron will store cookies in a similar location. Also note that Chromium will store cookies also in plain text inside the database so although there should be no reason for you to implement this yourself (since Electron most likely already does what you're trying to do) there should be no to only a low security risk in doing so.